# Question about Notation of Function

Tags: calculus

we represent function by letters f,g,h....etc, and the variable of the function are represented by x,y,.....etc.
Thus, the complete representation of function is done by f(x)= RULE . Now The letter y represents the output of the function.
Here, f(x) represents our function, we read f(x) as --> "function of the variable x" meaning we have the Rule as our function and x is the variable in it. thus, this is our complete representation of function with its output.

Now, if this is our complete representation of Function along with its output. Then why many people say f(x) and y both represents the output of the function if we represent the [output of the function with y] and [our function with f(x)] then why people mix both the representations ?
if we have seprate representation (y) for the output of the function and and seprate representation f(x) for our function. then why people say f(x) and y both represents the output of the function.

This is making me very much confused please help me.

Comment: "if we have seprate representation (y) for the output of the function and and seprate representation f(x) for our function" $f(x)$ also represents output of the function. for example you have the function $f(x)=x^2$ then if you give $x=3$ as the input then you have: $f(3)=3^2=9$ and $f(3)=9$ is your output

Comment: Yeah to be honest the notations for functions are so abused, it's easy to imagine no one understands it.

Comment: The problem is with your claim that $f(x)$ represents the function. That is false. $f(x)$ represents the output of the function at $x$. If you want to refer to the function itself, write $f$.

Comment: then what does "y" mean when we write f(x)=y....

Comment: You just answered your own question. By writing $f(x) = y$, you are defining $y$ and $f(x)$ to be the same thing.

Comment: @Shashwat singh The "reason" why we'd want to introduce a new variable $y$ is because writing equations in terms of $x$ and $y$ is the convention for _graphing_ equations. Graphing an equation allows us to visualize these objects. So when you write $y = f(x)$, you are indicating you want to consider the _graph_ of $f$.

Comment: Thanks SenZen for helping me....

Comment: Thanks SenZen for helping me. Please help me with this doubt also, ok if f  is the function and f(x) is the value of the function at x  then if i want to represent the function only by name. For example can i write f=2x meaning my function is 2x and i have named it f. please can you explain me this concept in detail, it would be very kind of you....

Comment: @Shashwat singh Good questions! Before I answer, I need to know what you know. First of all, are you familiar with what a set is?

Comment: thanks for replying I was eagerly waiting. yes, I know what are sets.

Comment: Thanks for help i understand that f denotes the function and f(x) denotes the value of f when plugging in x for the argument of the function. Speaking of "the function f(x)" is what mathematicians call "abuse of notation.
But, yes The notation f(x) to denote a function remains because it is often more convenient, and it is especially prominent from high school mathematics up to calculus because it is psychologically easier to become accustomed to.

Comment: SenZen if i want to represent the function only by name. For example can i write f=2x meaning my function is 2x and i have named it f.SenZen please can you explain me this concept in detail(not in comments) by answering my question. it would be very kind of you if you can write an answer for me.Please.

Comment: @Shashwat singh Yes yes I'll make an answer, but first I need to know what you know. Ok so you know about sets good. Now the real question: Do you know what the definition of a function is?

Comment: SenZen yes i know the defination of function that is a function is a special type of relation which associates each element of set A to a unique element in set B. I want to know about the representation of function.

Answer (score 1):

$f = \{ (x, y) : x \in \mathbb{R}, y = 2x\}$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116879/discussion-on-answer-by-senzen-question-about-notation-of-function).

Comment: @Daniel Fisher then make it so you get notifications for messages in chat.

Comment: SenZen f(x) is another way of writing y, f(x) and y they both are used to represent the output thats why we write f(x)=y because the both mean the same thing. Right ?

Comment: SenZen ?.......

Comment: yes $~~~~~~~~~~~$